# Error: 'Couldn't set up Steam data'

Tags: steam

I try to install steam on my laptop but when I try to open the steam, there is a notice says that "Couldn't set up Steam data - please contact technical support". What should I do? Please help me what to do right now

[image]

Comment: Please run `steam` in a terminal and add any out put to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the .steam folder(hidden)... press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to show hidden folders, then delete .steam in your home directory, and re-install steam through wherever you got it in the first place. Follow the setup instructions, then viola!